# iPhoto Smart Album for non-geotagged photos?

Tags: photos.app, geolocation

Is it possible to make a Smart Album in iPhoto that gathers all the photos without any location info, to facilitate geo-tagging them?  I can't seem to find "lack of location" as a filtering option on its own for Smart Albums, but I'm hoping someone can finagle a sideways solution that comes out to the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Smart Album

Create a smart album with the following rule:

> Photo + is not + tagged with GPS

To start, use the menu item: Photos.app > File (menu) > New Smart Album…

[image: Photos.app smart album]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a regular album not a smart one and then use the search box to look for the geographic location, example "Paris". Once you find it, select Paris from the search results, it will show all the pictures you took in Paris and then add the moments to your new album.

Comment: My question was about NON-geotagged photos, finding all the photos that DON'T have geolocation info. This answer is about how to find photos that ARE geotagged.